# Large gap between columns in D3js column chart

Tags: d3.js

In [this](https://codepen.io/centem/pen/dyoqoPM?editors=1010) codepen I am trying to create a column chart with scaleBand for the x and width. But, I have a large gap between the second and third columns. Why is it doing that? The full D3 code is below but the codepen also has the data that I am using for the column chart. Thank you.

```
data.forEach(function(d) {
  d.height = +d.height;
});

var w = 400;
var h = 400;

var xScale = d3.scaleBand()
.domain(["Burj Khalifa", "hanghai Tower", "Abraj Al-Bait Clock Tower",
         "Ping An Finance Centre", "Lotte World Tower", "One World Trade Center",
         "Guangzhou CTF Finance Center"])
.range([0, 400])
.paddingInner(0.3)
.paddingOuter(0.3);

var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
.domain([0,828])
.range([0,400]);

var svg = d3.select("#chart-area").append("svg")
.attr("width", w)
.attr("height", h);

var rects = svg.selectAll("rect")
.data(data);

rects.enter().append("rect")
  .attr("width", xScale.bandwidth)
  .attr("height", (d) => yScale(d.height))
  .attr("x", (d) => xScale(d.name))
  .attr("y", (d) => h - yScale(d.height))
  .attr("fill", "blue");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your domain array was not mapped correctly. Rather use your xScale using computed arrays which will avoid any spelling mistakes / special character interpretation.

Using this solves it.

```
var xScale = d3.scaleBand()
.domain(data.map(d => d.name))
.range([0, 400])
.paddingInner(0.3)
.paddingOuter(0.3);
```

Here is the [working codepen](https://codepen.io/Coola/pen/zYGJGEx?editors=1010).

Comment: That did it Coola. I didn't know about the D3 .map method. I do now. Thanks.

Comment: it is not a d3 method. It is a regular array method in javascript.